# r-concatenate for n elements from list

Tags: r, string, list

I am trying to read data from a column and then concatenate my desired information into a string.

So far I wrote R script successful for a single string input, but I can't mange to do it for `n` elements.

```
reprows <- strsplit("Day1_XExp2B3_500x_Y_Z", "_", fixed = T)
lenreprows <- length(reprows[[1]])
temprepnamelisttopaste <- c(2:(lenreprows-2))
temprepname <- paste(sapply(reprows[temprepnamelisttopaste]),collapse='.')
```

Data looks like in each row:

```
Day1_XExp2B3_500x_Y_Z
```

My output should be:

```
XExp2B3.500x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
## a function for re-concatenation
rc <- function (u) paste0(u[2:(length(u)-2L)], collapse = ".")
## main code
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, "_", fixed = T), rc))
```

where `x` is your character column with many elements. I made a simple test with

```
x <- rep("Day1_XExp2B3_500x_Y_Z", 2)
```

and the codes gives

```
#[1] "XExp2B3.500x" "XExp2B3.500x"
```

Looks like working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`strsplit` produces a list when you pass it a vector, so you need an `*apply` function to manipulate each result. Regex may be a more straightforward option, depending on what you know about the strings:

```
x <- c("Day1_XExp2B3_500x_Y_Z", "Day1_XExp2B3_500x_Y_Z")

sub("\\w+_(\\w+)_(\\w+)_._.", "\\1.\\2", x)
## [1] "XExp2B3.500x" "XExp2B3.500x"
```